# Django save two models with two foreign keys

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

One Article can have only 1 current Revision, but can have multiple revisions in history. Each Revision belongs to Article.

Models:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    current_revision = models.ForeignKey('Revision', related_name='current_revision', blank=False, default=None)

class Revision(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey('Article', null=True)
    title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=250, blank=False, default='(no title)')
    content = RedactorField('Content')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField('Slug', blank=False, null=True)
```

View:

```
if article_form.is_valid() and revision_form.is_valid():
    article = article_form.save(commit=False)
    revision = revision_form.save()
    article.current_revision = revision
    article.save()
    print(article)
    revision.article = article
    revision.save()
```

Is it okay to call `save` 3 times? Or is it possible to save 2 models with 2 saves?

Comment: You can `save()` as many times as you want, I don't see any problem with that.

Comment: I would think that making the FK to revision nullable would make more sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to call `save()` 3 times, but, about your implementation. 
I think, your models are not the best way to represent

*One Article can have only 1 current Revision, but can have multiple revisions in history*

Why not just, use a flag, to know if a revision is the current one, is better to check attributes than navigate between relationships

```
    class Article(models.Model):
        published = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Revision(models.Model):
        article = models.ForeignKey('Article', null=True)
        title = models.CharField('Title', max_length=250, blank=False, default='(no title)')
        content = RedactorField('Content')
        created_at = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now=True)
        slug = models.SlugField('Slug', blank=False, null=True)
        current = models.BooleanField(default=True)

#In your views 

if article_form.is_valid() and revision_form.is_valid():
    article = article_form.save()
    #set prior current revision flag to False
    last_current_revision = article.revision_set.filter(current=True)
    last_current_revision.update(current=False)
    revision = revision_form.save()
    revision.article = article
    revision.save()
```

In this way is less confusing.